# How to curl in django like php

Tags: php, python, django, curl, telegram

I want to send image to my telegram channel with my telegram bot. I know how to curl image with PHP, but i can't curl it with Django.

Here is php way :

```
     $bot_url    = "https://api.telegram.org/botxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/";
     $chat_id = "@mychannel";
     $url        = $bot_url . "sendPhoto?chat_id=" . $chat_id ;
     $post_fields = array('chat_id'   => $chat_id,
        'photo'     => new CURLFile(realpath("1.jpg"))
    );
    $ch = curl_init(); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
        "Content-Type:multipart/form-data"
    ));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_fields); 
    $output = curl_exec($ch);
```

I want to curl it in Django.

**Note :** my Django version is 1.10

Comment: SO isn't a code conversion service. You need to make an effort and try something yourself. If you get stuck on something specific, come back, show us what you've tried and we can take it from there.

Comment: Try to code a little and then come ask for help when you get stuck. See: http://pycurl.io/

Comment: Why do people keep up voting this question? The OP shows _no_ effort trying to solve the issue or _any_ research effort at all.

Answer (score 1):

As Piyush mentioned install requests.

```
import requests

requests.get('http://www.example.com/')
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `requests` package to do these work in an efficient way:

```
pip install requests
```

Refer [python-requests Documentation](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) on how to use it.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of options coming with most python installations.

## [urllib](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib.html)

```
import urllib
data = urllib.urlopen('https://google.com')
print data.read()
```

### [urllib2](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib2.html)

```
import urllib2
req = urllib2.Request('http://example.com', data='?foo=bar')
data = urllib2.urlopen(req)
print data.read()
```

### [httplib](https://docs.python.org/2/library/httplib.html)

```
import httplib
conn = httplib.HTTPSConnection("www.stackoverflow.com")
conn.request("GET", "/")
resp = conn.getresponse()
resp.status
#301
conn.close()
```

and ofcourse, as mentioned above, there is another excellent library named requests -))